# SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'origType' of undefined or null reference jquery-1.9.1.js, line 2865 character 5

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASPNET MVC4 app which uses JQuery and JQueryUI.
I have a jqueryui dialog and the jquery remove() throws a javascript error.

I've tried different combinations of jquery/jqueryui but not matter what the error occurs.

I've also included the jquery migrate.

Has anyone seen this error?
Is there a combination of jquery/jqueryui which will work?

I'm testing with IE10.

This works just fine in a plain HTML app without MVC4.

Here's the code, it's the very last line, removing the jquery object with remove(), destroyForm runs when the dialog is closed:

```
var loadDialog = function(url, caption, formName) {

        var dialogID = "dialogholder" + dialogStack.length;
        var markup = $("<div id=" + dialogID  + "></div>");
        markup.appendTo('body');
        var dialog = $("#" + dialogID).load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
                                            if (status == "error") {
                                                var msg = "Error loading url: ";
                                                alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                ko.applyBindings(null, dialog.find('form').get(0));//bind to the last form in the model i.e. the form about to be shown in the dialog                                
                                                //store the form name so that the destory form function can remove from client model
                                                if (formName)
                                                    $.extend(dialog, { formName: formName} );
                                                else
                                                    $.extend(dialog, { formName: dialog.find('form').get(0).id} );
                                            }
                                        }
        ).dialog( { modal: true, title: caption, width: "900px", resizable: true, close: destroyForm } );


        dialogStack.push(dialog);
    };

    function destroyForm()
    {
        var dialog = dialogStack.pop();
        topoix.destroy(dialog.formName);
        dialog.dialog('destroy');//return element to original state.
        dialog.remove();//remove element from DOM
    }
```